# help with differential equation $xy^2y'=x+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me with this? The question says to solve the differential equation $$xy^2y'=x+1$$

so I separated the $y$'s and the $x$'s and got $y'y^2=x+\frac{1}{x}$ then integrated and got
$(y^3/3)+c=\frac{x^2}{x}+x+\ln x$.

I'm not sure if this is correct and even if it is I'm not where to go from here. Do I solve for $c$ or for $y$ or neither?

Comment: You solve for $y$. You should always read $y$ as $y(x)$. Just writing $y$ is an abuse of notation.

Comment: The right-side went bad. You want to integrate $1+\frac{1}{x}$, the integral is $x+\ln(|x|)+C$.

Answer (score 1):

Your process was correct, but there was a slight issue where you divided by $x$ and that in turn caused the integration issue.

You should have:

$$y^3(x)  =  3 \left( x + \ln x + c \right)$$

You can now take the cube root of each side.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. Just make sure you understand that the solution is valid either for $x>0$ or for $x<0$.

Solution is expressed as
$$
y=\sqrt[3]{c+3x+3\log x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xy^2y'=x+1\rightarrow xy^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x+1\rightarrow y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+1}{x}$$

Separation of variables:

$$(y^2)dy=\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)dx$$

Yay you can now integrate!

$$\int y^2dy=\int \frac{x+1}{x}dx=\int \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx$$

$$\frac{y^3}{3}=\int \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx=x+\ln|x|+C$$

$$y^3=3(x+\ln|x|+C)$$

$$\therefore y=\sqrt[3]{3(x+\ln|x|+C)}$$